# How to handle "/Date(1262476800000)/"

Tags: python, .net, date, datetime

Recently I received this output from an API (I think it's .NET driven).. What kind of date format is this and how do I convert it to a Python date object?

```
{
    Id: 10900001,
    ExpirationDate: "/Date(1262476800000)/",
}
```

It seems a timestamp but I get parse errors on `fromtimestamp()`

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.fromtimestamp(float('1262476800000'))
ValueError: 'year is out of range'
```

Comment: that's expirationDate, maybe long long time. 40000 year.

Comment: It's a [Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), possibly including milliseconds. Try divide the timestamp by 1000 and convert it again.

Comment: @luoluo's answer is much correct here !

Answer (score 4):

You are getting the error because the timestamp is in milliseconds. You just remove the last 3 digits and it will work -

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
>>> s = '1262476800540'
>>> d = datetime.fromtimestamp(float(s[:-3]))
>>> d = d + timedelta(milliseconds=int(s[-3:]))
>>> print d
2010-01-03 05:30:00.540000
```

Comment: This may lose the milliseconds parts.

Comment: @luoluo Updated the code to include milliseconds as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> a = datetime.fromtimestamp(float('1262476800002')/1000)
>>> a.microsecond
2000
```

Comment: This may lose the milliseconds parts, no offence meant :)

Comment: Are you sure? @VikasNehaOjha

Comment: OMG... Its wonderful. Apologies!

Answer (score 1):

As it seems the API's output is `JSON`, I would assume it is a javascript timestamp. To convert it to python, remove the milliseconds and you should be fine.

From an online conversion tool http://www.epochconverter.com/

```
GMT: Sun, 03 Jan 2010 00:00:00 GMT
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a UNIX time stamp in milliseconds. In other words 1262476800(000) = 2010-01-03T00:00:00+00:00

Could that be correct?

You can use fromtimestamp to convert it to a date object.

Cheers,
Anders

Comment: I ruled that out, because I was expecting an expiration date to be in the future, not five years ago.

Comment: They might have used some other base time when creating the timestamp. In C# you could do something like this. Maybe they used something other than 1970.

static DateTime ConvertFromUnixTimestamp(double timestamp)
{
    DateTime origin = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    return origin.AddSeconds(timestamp);
}

In any case, it's clear from the value that the timestamp contains only date and not time.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use `time` module.

```
In [13]: import time

In [14]: time.ctime(1262476800000)
Out[14]: 'Mon Apr 19 02:00:00 41976\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to peruse the documentation of that API. Failing which, can you reverse-engineer it? If you can create entities in that system, then do so. If you create 3 entities expiring on 1st Jan 2016, 11th Jan 2016 and 21st Jan 2016, you'll be able to see if it's (probably) a linearly increasing sequence of time-units and deduce what are the units and the base-date. Even if you can't create entities, can you get the dates in human-readable format through a human-orientated web interface?

Once you know what the number represents, you can decode it either into year, month, day ... fields, or into a number of seconds since the canonical base date (timestamp).

Or maybe you'll get lucky and another reader will recognise the format!

Comment: Also can you establish what OS and/or database is storing the data? Native date/time representation for the system, available date/time field formats for the DB, might help you.